# Floating point exception: 8 on Smith number check

Tags: c++, number-theory

So I have written a code to check if a long int number is Smith, but I keep getting Floating point exception: 8, no matter what size do I fix my variables in. Not quite sure what I am missing.

```
#include <iostream>

 bool isPrime(long int k) { 
   if (k == 1) return false;  
   for (long int i = 2; i*i < k; i++) 
    if (k % i == 0) 
        return false; 

return true; 
} 

int main(){

long int n;
std::cin >> n;
long int sumPr = 0, sumCif = 0;
 while (n > 0) { 
    sumCif += n % 10; 
    n = n/10; 
}

for (long int i = 0; i*i<=n/2; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        while (n % i == 0){
            long int p = i;
            while (p > 0) { 
            sumPr += (p % 10); 
            p = p/10; 
        } 
            n = n/i;
        }
    }
}
 if (sumPr == sumCif) std::cout << "1" ; else std::cout << "0";
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `n = n/i` - possible division by zero here.

Comment: Note that your `isPrime` will fail for squares of primes.

Comment: Your `isPrime` returns `true` for `0`. Which means you are dividing by `0`, on `n=n/i;`

Answer (score 0):

The limits of this loop appear to be flawed:

```
for (long int i = 0; i*i<=n/2; i++) {
```

Possibly partly due to copy and paste from `isPrime()`.  But the larger problem is you need to modularize this code so that you can properly test each component.  And reuse modules (e.g. you implement sum of digits of a number twice in your code.)  Code duplication is a potential source of error.

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPrime(long number) { 
    if (number < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return (number == 2);
    }

    for (long divisor = 3; divisor * divisor <= number; divisor += 2) {
        if (number % divisor == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true; 
}

long sum_digits(long number) {
    long sum = 0;

    while (number > 0) { 
        sum += number % 10; 
        number /= 10; 
    }

    return sum;
}

long sum_prime_factor_digits(long number) {
    long sum = 0;

    for (long divisor = 2; divisor <= number; divisor++) {
        if (isPrime(divisor)) {
            while (number % divisor == 0) {
                sum += sum_digits(divisor);
                number /= divisor;
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

bool is_smith(long number) {
    if (isPrime(number)) {
        return false;  // only composites can play this game
    }

    return sum_digits(number) == sum_prime_factor_digits(number);
}

int main() {
    long number;
    std::cin >> number;

    if (is_smith(number)) {
        std::cout << "1";
    } else {
        std::cout << "0";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0; 
}
```

**TESTS**

```
> ./a.out
4
1
> ./a.out
5
0
> ./a.out
6
0
> ./a.out
22
1
> ./a.out
4937775
1
> ./a.out
15966114
1
>
```

Writing clean code isn't something you do after the fact, it's what you do to help you in the debugging process.